# MariaDB Log Rotate Errors

Tags: ubuntu, mariadb

Every night, I get an email from my server with the following:

```
/etc/cron.daily/logrotate:
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mysql.log /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log '
run-parts: /etc/cron.daily/logrotate exited with return code 1
```

I don't know why this is happening, and I can't figure out how to stop the error.

Comment: Do u have mariadb installed on your server ?  It look like that your cron program is not able to access the db.

Answer (score 1):

There is linux utility logrotate, It is trying to rotate logs of mariadb.

You should look in file:

```
/etc/logrotate.conf
```

Look for section which has scripts(**which sends you mails**), Headed by:

```
/var/log/mysql.log {
...
...
...
} 
/var/log/mysql/mysql.log {
...
...
...
}
/var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log {
...
...
...
}
```

Maybe because credentials are not being entered. Either remove these scripts(hash them) if not wanted, Or give login credentials to MariaDB.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Did someone recently set a password for root? Your log rotate probably needs a /root/.my.cnf or /home/root/.my.cnf which has the password in it so that the log rotation piece is able to get into mysql and flush the logs.

You may have a single mysql log file that is filling up because of the failed rotation, maybe even a deleted file that is being held open. This would get corrected on a restart or flush of the related logs. If you run out of disk space, but can't find a large file doing it, this could easily be the cause. The deleted file doesn't actually get deleted until all use is removed which includes MariaDB or MySQL holding it open for writing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably set/changed your root password.

If you are on Debian, you can update it in `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`.

Comment: First line of this file says: `# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!` I have the same issue and I never touched this file.

Answer (score 0):

- go to your mysql/mariadb client and assure that *debian-sys-maint* user with empty password is already present in *user* table of *mysql* database
- default `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` should contain **debian-sys-maint** as *user* instead of **root**

```
# Automatically generated for Debian scripts. DO NOT TOUCH!
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysql_upgrade]
host     = localhost
user     = debian-sys-maint
password =
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
basedir  = /usr
```